# Java Deployment and Configuration (1.6.0_21)

Tags: java, deployment

Sofware: Java Runtime Environment 1.6.0_21

OS: Windows XP Professional 32-Bit, SP3

Situation: a new piece of web based software is being deployed this week and prior to this all the company desktops need to be set up to meet the requirements of this software. One of these requirements is JRE 1.6.0_21.

I have successfully scripted the removal of all other Java versions and the installation of the required version, however I cannot get it configured properly.

One of the requirements is that the Java console be set to disabled - if it is not it can cause an issue with a particular function. I have pushed out a deployment.config and deployment.properties but the console just will not disable itself.. I know the config is being read correctly because the update tab is being correctly disabled and removed.

deployment.config:

```
deployment.system.config=file\:C\:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=true
```

deployment.properties:

```
#deployment.properties
#Fri Jun 15 09:34:31 EST 2012
deployment.version=6.0
deployment.console.startup.mode=DISABLE
deployment.javaws.autodownload=NEVER
deployment.javaws.autodownload.locked=
```

There is no change if I set the console to ENABLE either - it remains on the default of hidden.

I'm sure I can disable the console with a registry change of some form but my preference is to have it done via the deployment files as it gives the option of centralising the properties file to a network share if we wish.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you do it trough Active Directory (GPO)? This would also be "centralised"

Comment: I could, but as far as I'm aware the only way to manage Java though group policy is just by using it to modify the registry - technically yes this is also centralised but I still prefer to use the built in management methods.

Comment: GPO is all about registry... :)

Comment: By the way... 
The valid properties for deployment.console.startup.mode are:

`•"HIDE" to hide the Java Console;
•"SHOW" to show the Java Console;
•"DISABLE" to disable the Java Console;`

Can you test `SHOW` to see if it would work? (You seem to have used "ENABLED")

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I had tried it on SHOW as well. As it turns out this morning it's working.. I have no idea why, nothing was so much as rebooted before I went home but today, logged the test machine off then back on again and everything is fine.

Comment: Also yes, you're right about GPO and registry, however I mean there aren't any existing settings I know of, I'd need to create a custom admin template which may or may not work later on after changes/updates/etc. Easy enough to fix of course but supported management methods tend to be my first choice :).

Answer (score 1):

OK - it is now working. I have no idea why - I changed nothing last night before I went home, came back this morning and logged back into the test machine (which hadn't even been shut down) and found it working exactly how it should.

If anyone has an idea why it might of happened would be nice to leave here for anyone else who has the same problem.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't install Java on the system.   I would simply copy a JDK (not JRE) installed directory from another machine into C:\Java\JDK1.X.0_XX  and then define JAVA_HOME and put JAVA_HOME/bin in the PATH.  Then you don't need to worry about any JRE stuff that the JRE or JDK installed on the system.